# "Error 401 (OAuth2 Error)!!1" running onInstall()

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-apps-script-addon

I have a script that has been working years. This week, the menu stopped working; for all users.

Actual code:

```
function onInstall(){
  onOpen();
}

function onOpen(){
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu("Script→")
  .addItem("ny underrubrik: StartStrategi", "start")
  .addItem("ny underrubrik: Förvaltning", "forvaltning")
  .addItem("ny underrubrik: Incident", "incident")
  .addToUi()
}
```

In the script-editor when running onInstall manually, I get the "Authorization required"-popup but it referees to "Untitled project" instead of my named one. This may be why I get the 401-error when I click "Review Permissions".

Creating a new script with the same code got around the problem but came with the new issue of not being able to delete either of them; tried multiple users.

onInstall still don't trigger as the 1st script is broken.